# System/3: Accessing compilers from tape

Tags: ibm, mainframe

I started getting into playing with the IBM System/3 emulator from simh, and found [this tape](http://www.bitsavers.org/bits/IBM/System_3/5702-pp1.zip) - looking at the listing it looks like there's a COBOL and RPG II compiler on that tape. What would be the procedures to attach it to the emulator, and the OCL to use them? Do I need to copy it to a disk first or...?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: A zip file?  Heck no!

Comment: So what's in the zip file? Please post a listing.

Comment: I voted to close pending more info, specifically what's in the zip.